# OneSignal Notifications not appearing in Xamarin Forms Android - Release Mode

Tags: firebase, xamarin, xamarin.forms, android-notifications, onesignal

I'm using OneSignal SDK for notifications with Xamarin Forms - when I run the app in Debug mode, the notifications arrive on the device.

However, when compiling and running in Release mode, no notifications appear on the device (Android One).

I suspect maybe something is being stripped out (by the compiler / linker?) - but I'm not sure how to resolve this.

The app runs in Release mode, however, in some cases seems to crash and the logs indicate the following:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.onesignal.GcmBroadcastReceiver" on path: DexPathList.......



androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateReceiver
java.lang.InstantiationException: java.lang.Class<com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver> cannot be instantiated


androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateService
java.lang.InstantiationException: java.lang.Class<com.onesignal.RestoreKickoffJobService> cannot be instantiated
```

Answer (score 1):

This type of message is caused by ProGuard / R8. You can disable it or you can add specific rules to the Proguard.cfg file to prevent code from being stripped out.

Comment: @Steve it is expected to say thanks by upvoting. Saying literary thanks is strongly discouraged in terms of site.

Answer (score 0):

For others that may be seeing the same issue this is what fixed it for me:

1. Create an empty file in the Android project proguard.cfg. Set the build action to ProguardConfiguration
2. Add the following

```
-keep class com.onesignal.** { *; }
-keep class com.google.firebase.** { *; }
```

Re-build and redeploy.